# Cannot import angular module in VSCode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I tried to import NgForm in angular with the following import

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form';
```

It searches for node modules folder in src/app which is why it returns an error. The node modules folder is 2 levels up from the app folder.

However when I try the following path

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
```

It works no problem. Why is this? I use vscode, so the first path is the default way that VScode auto-imported NgForm.

Comment: It is a TypeScript issue It is still happening in v2.6.2 but it looks like we shouldn't have to wait long for this to get fixed. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to Angular v4 no longer support deep imports like this.

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form';
```

Comment: Do you know how I can auto-import the correct way in VScode editor?

Comment: it will show a bulb icon in yello when you hove over NgForm. you can click that

Comment: did that help you?

Comment: I do not any see lightbulb when I do that. I want the auto import to not do a deep import. Just do @angular/core

Comment: Sorry I installed all of those packages and it is still same.